# Entity Database is not updating

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added extra entities upon the IdentityModels in Visual Studio 2015. However, After updating the database and adding the migrations nothing changes in the database. In fact, all the tables are the same even if I delete some entity in the model or by adding new ones. The migration contains the entities that I added, however, the role entity is added manually as I have found an alternative solution where I added the column manually to the SQL server than I have edited the migration class. However, some other existed entities are not updated yet.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.RoleId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Roles = c.String(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ClaimType = c.String(),
                    ClaimValue = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
            c => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your migrations? And screenshot of which tables should be deleted?

Comment: _adding the migrations_ !== *apply migrations*

Comment: I am trying to add new columns to the database but its not working